# shouldComponentUpdate() only executing once

Tags: reactjs

```js
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        if (this.props.marker != nextProps.marker)
        {
            return false;
        }
      }
```

First time

this.props.marker = "v" nextProps.marker = "s"

returns false, as it should.

Second time

this.props.marker = "s" nextProps.marker = "s"

Skips the function shouldComponentUpdate...if statement is not executed.

Comment: Can it be that the parent component re-rendered, which causees this component to be re-rendered too (which makes it seem that shouldComponentUpdate wasn't called)? Maybe you can debug what by checking if componentDidMount was called multiple times.

Comment: Because the if condition fails... 's' === 's' why would they be unequal?

Comment: What should happen if `this.props.marker != nextProps.marker` is `false`?

Answer (score 0):

```js
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        if (this.props.marker != nextProps.marker)
        {
            return false;
        }

        //Adding the else if, fixes the problem
        else if(this.props.marker == nextProps.marker){

            return true;
        }
      }
```